# Relationship creation issues in VS2013

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Ok, I got 2 questions.. If i make a relation of Primary Key and Foreign Key in VS2010, will it hold and work in VS2013 as well, seeing as i did all the work in master database instead of making another one (stupid, i know... but i didn't know about not being able to construct relationships using relation Diagrams on master DB). Also, if i generate scripts of my current DB, create another DB and execute the script there. Will it work?

Secondly, i have two dates.. i want to count number of days using the joining date and releasing date. (these dates are stored in Patients table, i want to take the difference and store it in Cost table). is it possible?

I know i haven't provided any code, but any kind of assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the -1 who ever did it. I tried googling but found nothing. now can i PLEASE get a response? instead of negative marking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you generate scripts for your database it should work on every version of sql server. Please remember you cant create new datatype like geography, geometry etc in old versions of sql server.

You can use function **DATEDIFF** directly in sql server for example **DATEDIFF(day,'2008-06-05','2008-08-05')**

If you want to calculate this in c# you can directly subtract two **datetime** objects like **(Date1.Date - Date2.Date).Days**

Comment: and can i add the result into another table? Thank you very much for responding :)